# Logarithmic to linear

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, inverse

Given this function:

$$\frac{1.0}{1024.0} + \frac{x}{100.0} * \frac{1023.0}{1024.0} = y$$
$$10 * \frac{\log_{10}(y)}{\log_{10}(2)} = z$$
$$z * 100 = a$$

```
    So f(0) = 10000 & f(100) = 0.
```

I need to find the inverse. It would be really helpful if I could see the steps.
Thanks!

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Where is the definition of the function $f$ ? What are $x$, $y$, $z$, $a$ ?

Comment: What is $f(k)$? Is $a$ a constant? If so, $x,y,z$ are all determined surely?

Comment: Clearly I'm not versed in writing math functions. The three lines define function f. x is the variable, y is the result of the 1st line, y is the result of 2nd line and z is the result of the 3rd line. a is the result of the function f.

Comment: So you have $a=f(x)$ and you want to find a function $g$ so that $x=g(a)$ is that right?

Comment: You have $a=h\log(kx)$ where $h,k$ are constants, so $kx=10^{a/h}$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where f() is defined, so I'll just solve the one equation with a log in it and hope that helps you...

$$10*\frac{log_{10}(y)}{log_{10}(2)}=z$$
using the change of bases formula
$$10*log_{2}(y)=z$$
$$log_{2}(y)=\frac{z}{10}$$
$$2^{log_{2}(y)}=2^\left(\frac{z}{10}\right)$$
$$y=2^\left(\frac{z}{10}\right)$$

in terms of a

$$y=2^{10a}$$

hope that helps!!!

oops, just saw your note!

$$a=100z$$
$$a=100*10*log_{2}(y)$$
$$a=1000*log_{2}\left(\frac{1}{1024}+\frac{1023}{102400}*x\right)$$

Comment: only issue I see is that f(0)=-10000 instead of 10000

Comment: So f(0) = -10000 with the original function. With the inverse f(0) = 100, & f(-10000) = 0. This was an answer given on another site but for the life of me can't figure out how he got this. This tests perfectly though;
    $$\frac{x}{1000.0} + 10 = y$$
    $$100.0 * (2^y - 1) = z$$
    $$\frac{z}{1023.0} = a$$

Comment: Sorry, just fixed the exponent

Comment: yup, those certainly work, but the overall function is different.  how did they come up with it?  you got me